# Default HTTP method for outbound endpoint in MULE ESB

Tags: http, mule

What is the default HTTP method that an outbound endpoint in MULE uses? For example, if I have the following endpoint:

```
<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
    address="https://api.example.com/makeCall">
```

Will the message be sent with a GET or POST?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `method` property of an HTTP/HTTPS outbound endpoint is not required, there is no default property set by Mule - according to the [Mule documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference).

However, [this blog post](http://javatrycatch.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/mule-issue-http-method-or-content-type.html) suggests that the default method for an outbound endpoint, like the one in your example, is `POST`. Since this blog post isn't official, I can't guarantee it's reliability. Hope this helps!